# T-SQL: convert row into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would have the data like this

| Id | Name | Attributes | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product_1 | red | color |
| 2 | Product_1 | small | size |
| 3 | Product_2 | red | color |
| 4 | Product_2 | large | size |

and I want it to be like this

| Name | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product_1 | red | small |
| Product_2 | red | large |

I have tried pivot but cannot find the way

```
select Name, [Color], [Size] from 
(
    select Name, [Type] , Attributes
    from @temp_table ) AS sourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Attributes)
    FOR  [Type] IN ([Color], [Size])
) as pivot_table
```

Comment: please show us your attempted pivot query

Comment: @Squirrel I Found it

Comment: Your code seems to work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff101b920198ad275cbcfb4f71480e7b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that there is nothing wrong in my code.

```
select fcId, [Color], [Size] from 
(
    select Id, [Type] , Attribute
    from @temp_table ) AS sourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Attribute)
    FOR  [Type] IN ([Color], [Size])
) as pivot_table
```